# Strip trailing non numeric characters

Tags: vba, excel

How can I strip trailing non numeric characters.

Input:

```
GWS9001SWE
GD2345UU
345AS
Y5B
```

Output:

```
GWS9001
GD2345
345
Y5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a simple formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:$50)/(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$50),1))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

UDF (user-defined function). Use it like ordinary function.

```
Function StripValue(cell)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True: .Pattern = "[a-z]+$"
        StripValue = .Replace(cell.Value, "")
    End With
End Function
```